# Mark a bug as Resolved

Tags: azure-devops

I went to `Team Explorer`, there was a comment section for `"Check In"` which I entered my comment and checked in the code, so now if I go to `pending changes` they are not showing there. 
But I remember there was another drop down option that they showed me we should mark it as "`Resolved`" too, I can't find that. Note that I don't mean merge conflicts resolve tho.
Where is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Resolve function just` when you have conflit between source cnotrol server version and your local version, this is often the case after Checkout.

But if you have committed,  source control considers your merge successful `=>` you don't have Resolve function.